# Not scrolling in React

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a function in React. I am getting some text information from an API call. I save it in a variable. I then use map to convert it into HTML and show it on the website and just a paragraph of text. But now the page doesn't scroll. Is there a better way of doing this? Or solving it?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Log.css'


function NewlineText(props) {
    const text = props.text;
    const newText = text.split('\n').map((str) => <p className="text">{str}</p>);

    return newText;
}

function Log() {
    const [date, setDate] = useState("");
    const [data, setData] = useState("");
    const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
    useEffect (() => {
        fetch('https://www.{api_website_url}.com/api/log').then(res => res.json()).then((result) =>{
            setDate(result.last_modified);
            setData(result.log);
            setStatus(result.status);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="page">
            <Link to="/"><button className="button1">
                Home
            </button></Link>
            <div className="logs">
                <NewlineText text={data} />
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <p className="text">Date Last Modified: {date}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Log;
```

Comment: What does the data look like going into the newline function? You can also destructure props as data and return the map in one line. Can you edit with what you're passing as data?

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

or

```
 overflow: scroll;
 white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I tried all of these combinations :(